# Is it possible to open devtools programmatically with puppeteer?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, puppeteer

I'm testing my chrome extension with puppeteer, and I would like to see how it behaves when the devtools is closed and reopened.
When lauching the browser, I use

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            devtools: true,
            ...
});
```

which opens the devtools by default on a new page. I'd like to close it once the page is loaded and then reopen it.

The Axe team uses puppeteer for testing their extension: https://github.com/dequelabs/puppeteer-devtools/blob/develop/src/index.ts and they treat the devtools page as a regular page but I can't seem to be able to close/open it as I wish. As they mention, it's kinda hacky, and only possible on old Puppeteer versions.

I also tried:

- using puppeteer keyboard event to open the devtools, didn't work
- using the CDP protocol directly sending "Input.dispatchKeyEvent" messages, which is basically the previous option, didn't work either

Any other way to do that ?